# How to change an expression to Fortran90 form?

Tags: output-formatting, fortran

I have a large expression produced by *Mathematica*. To use this expression in my Fortran program I need to change it to a Fortran90 form. I am not satisfied with the `FortranForm` command.

The output of the  *Mathematica* expression is like this,

```
       -48*Sqrt[6]*E^((-2*S[1, x]^2)/bx - (S[1, y]^2)/bx - (S[1, z]^2)/
        bz - (S[2, x]^2)/bx - (S[2, y]^2)/bx - (S[2, z]^2)/
        bz - (Sp[1, x]^2)/bx - (Sp[1, y]^2)/bx - (Sp[1, z]^2)/bz)
         + 3*Sqrt[5*v]
```

I hope I can get this expression like this,

```
    -48.q0*sqrt(6.q0)*Exp((-(2.0*s1x**2/bx)-s1y**2/bx-s1z**2/bz  &
    -s2x**2/bx-s2y**2/bx - s2z**2/bz - sp1x**2/bx - sp1y**2/bx   &
    - sp1z**2/bz)+ 3.q0*Sqrt[5.q0*v]
```

Notice that:

1. The width should be fixed and there is a "&" at the end of the line. It is better the single line space can be fully occupied.
2. Some integers should be changed to reals. For example, `6` -> `6.q0` or `6.d0`;
3. It is better for `E^` to be changed to `Exp()` form.

How can I change `S[a,b]` to `Sab` easily? This is not a big problem. I could replace it in *Mathematica*.

Anyway, I want to change my *Mathematica* expression into a Fortran90 expression automaticly. Is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For simplicity and elegance I use Verbeia's nice Riffle-ing for continuation.
While it is possible to format real numbers as requested in FortranForm I always thought that this is way too complicated in Mathematica (the code below is slightly modified from my old FeynCalc-Write2 function described [here](http://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/Write2/)

```
myFortrantoggle=False; (* needed to avoid recursion *)
Clear[q];
Unprotect[Real];
Real/:Format[r_Real/;r>=0,FortranForm]:=({mantissa,exponent}=MantissaExponent[r];
If[r===0.,exponent=1];
SequenceForm[10. mantissa,q,exponent-1])/;(myFortrantoggle=!myFortrantoggle);
Protect[Real];
Unprotect[Times];
ClearAttributes[Times,Orderless];(* not really needed, but keeps order *)
step1=FortranForm[(-48*Sqrt[6]*E^((-2*S[1,x]^2)/bx-(S[1,y]^2)/bx-(S[1,z]^2)/bz-(S[2,x]^2)/bx-(S[2,y]^2)/bx-(S[2,z]^2)/bz-(Sp[1,x]^2)/bx-(Sp[1,y]^2)/bx-(Sp[1,z]^2)/bz)+3*Sqrt[5*v])/.
{Sqrt[a_]:>sqrt[N@a],Sqrt[i_Integer]Sqrt[f_Symbol]:>sqrt[N@i f],E^b_ :> exp[b]}/.
(j_Integer*x_):>(N[j]x)/.
{S[a_,b_]:>ToExpression[StringJoin["s",ToString[a],ToString[b]]],Sp[a_,b_]:>ToExpression[StringJoin["sp",ToString[a],ToString[b]]]}];
result=StringJoin@@Riffle[With[{splits=StringSplit[ToString@step1," "]},Fold[If[StringLength[Last@#1]+StringLength[#2]>60,Join[#1,{#2}],Join[Most[#1],{StringJoin[Last[#1],#2]}]]&,{First@splits},Rest[splits]]],"  &\n"];
SetAttributes[Times,Orderless];Protect[Times];
result
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes,  we can get nearly exact fortran format using your method.  After changing a little, I can use it. Thanks!

Comment: @Mertig I want to know, are there some special packages for changing Mathematica expressions to Fortran form more flexiblely? I think many people need this and someone maybe have done this work.

Comment: @Orders I don't know. I also don't think many people need this. You may have a look at [this](http://porthos.ist.utl.pt/docs/Format/Format.html), though it is quite old.

Comment: @Mertig Thanks. For the large expressions output, I am still a little worried about the above method. I need to find a more safe method, maybe.

Comment: @Mertig How to transform the expression in FortranForm? Just look at this, [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21519/how-to-change-the-integer-to-a-special-form-in-an-expression) Thanks!

Comment: @Rolf Mertig Your code works well! Thank you very much! Could you like to rewrite it to a personal function to make it easier to use?

Answer (score 9):

You can get a long way to your goal using `FortranForm` in *Mathematica* and some 
replacement rules. `ToExpression` and `ToString` are very useful for this kind of application. (I'm giving this one a name for later use below.)

```
step1 = FortranForm[(-48*Sqrt[6]*
  E^((-2*S[1, x]^2)/bx - (S[1, y]^2)/bx - (S[1, z]^2)/
     bz - (S[2, x]^2)/bx - (S[2, y]^2)/bx - (S[2, z]^2)/
     bz - (Sp[1, x]^2)/bx - (Sp[1, y]^2)/bx - (Sp[1, z]^2)/bz) + 
  3*Sqrt[5*v])] /. {S[a_, b_] :> ToExpression[StringJoin["s", ToString[a], ToString[b]]], 
  Sp[a_, b_] :>  ToExpression[StringJoin["sp", ToString[a], ToString[b]]]}
```

> ```
> -48*Sqrt(6)*E**
>  -    ((-2*s1x**2)/bx - s1y**2/bx - s1z**2/bz - s2x**2/bx - s2y**2/bx - 
>  -      s2z**2/bz - sp1x**2/bx - sp1y**2/bx - sp1z**2/bz) + 
>  -  3*Sqrt(5)*Sqrt(v)
> ```

However I don't think you can get your preferred format for integers using *Mathematica* alone. If you try to append a period (dot) to an integer expression, *Mathematica* will try to calculate the actual real-valued expression as shown, treating `q0` as a separate symbolic quantity:

```
FortranForm[(-48*Sqrt[6]*
     E^((-2*S[1, x]^2)/bx - (S[1, y]^2)/bx - (S[1, z]^2)/
         bz - (S[2, x]^2)/bx - (S[2, y]^2)/bx - (S[2, z]^2)/
         bz - (Sp[1, x]^2)/bx - (Sp[1, y]^2)/bx - (Sp[1, z]^2)/bz) + 
  3*Sqrt[5*v])] /. {S[a_, b_] :> ToExpression[StringJoin["s", ToString[a], ToString[b]]], 
  Sp[a_, b_] :> ToExpression[StringJoin["sp", ToString[a], ToString[b]]],
  z_Integer :> ToExpression[ToString[z]~StringJoin~".q0"]}
```

> ```
>    -117.57550765359254*E**
>  -    ((-2.*q0*s1x**(2.*q0))/bx**(1.*q0) - 
>  -      (1.*q0*s1y**(2.*q0))/bx**(1.*q0) - 
>  -      (1.*q0*s1z**(2.*q0))/bz**(1.*q0) - 
>  -      (1.*q0*s2x**(2.*q0))/bx**(1.*q0) - 
>  -      (1.*q0*s2y**(2.*q0))/bx**(1.*q0) - 
>  -      (1.*q0*s2z**(2.*q0))/bz**(1.*q0) - 
>  -      (1.*q0*sp1x**(2.*q0))/bx**(1.*q0) - 
>  -      (1.*q0*sp1y**(2.*q0))/bx**(1.*q0) - 
>  -      (1.*q0*sp1z**(2.*q0))/bz**(1.*q0))*q0**1.5 + 
>  -  6.708203932499369*q0**1.5*Sqrt(v)
> ```

Similarly, I'm not sure there is a programmatic way to convert the `E**` form to `exp(...)` form without building a more complex parser.

Here is a partial solution to your need for ampersands at the end of the line. The basic idea is to convert to a string, split at the appropriate length, and then `Riffle` in the ampersand and a line break.
However, you can't just break at the 80-character limit because that breaks expressions like `sp1z` across lines, which is not what you want. Probably what you should try is to split the string progressively at whitespace, and then build up piece-by-piece into strings of up to (but no more than) the desired number characters using `Fold`, like this (I've used 60 characters for illustrative purposes):

```
StringJoin @@ 
 Riffle[With[{splits = StringSplit[ToString@step1, " "]}, 
   Fold[If[StringLength[Last@#1] + StringLength[#2] > 60, 
      Join[#1, {#2}], 
      Join[Most[#1], {StringJoin[Last[#1], #2]}]] &, {First@splits}, 
    Rest[splits]] ], "  &\n"]
```

> ```
> -48*Sqrt(6)*E**((-2*s1x**2)/bx-s1y**2/bx-s1z**2/bz-s2x**2/bx  &
>   -s2y**2/bx-s2z**2/bz-sp1x**2/bx-sp1y**2/bx-sp1z**2/bz)+  &
>   3*Sqrt(5)*Sqrt(v)
> ```

Comment: here is another solution to insert  line - 
 breaks  cleverly :  `ToString[step1, InputForm, PageWidth -> 60]` It doesn't break expressions in the middle of a word

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanations. It is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

This changes E**argument to exp(argument):

```
Unprotect[Power];
Power /: Format[Power[E, x_], FortranForm] := exp[x]
Protect[Power];
{FortranForm[E^(3*z)], FortranForm[Exp[2*z^3]]}

(* Out: {exp(3*z), exp(2*z**3)} *)
```