# How to change the Integer to a special form in an expression?

Tags: expression-manipulation

---

I have an expression. I want to change all the Integers to a new form. The rule is,  x_Integer->x._f. But we should consider some special cases.
  For example,

```
  input = 22 +  4/5 x1 x1 x1 + (2 x2^4 + 343 Pi^4)/
  Sqrt[67 - x1 x1 x3 x3 + x2^(5/4)] + (4 x1 - x2)^(-3/2 q) + 
   Exp[-x1 x1 + 4 x2 x2 - 3 x1];
```

The output expression should be,

```
 output = 22. _f + E^(-3. _f x1 - x1^(2. _f) + 4. _f x2^(2. _f)) + (
     4. _f x1^(3. _f))/(5. _f) + (4. _f x1 - x2)^(-3. _f x3/2. _f) + (
  343. _f \[Pi]^(4. _f) + 2. _f x2^(4. _f))/Sqrt[
    67. _f + x2^(5. _f/4. _f) - x1^(2. _f) x3^(2. _f)];
```

So, how to construct the rule function?  Thanks!

Comment: Something like `ReplaceAll[input, x_?IntegerQ -> f[1. x]]` ?

Comment: not sure if you have this in mind, but does this work: `input /. {Rational[x_, y_] :>  Row[{x, ".", Blank[f]}]/Row[{y, ".", Blank[f]}], x_?NumberQ :> Row[{x, ".", Blank[f]}]}`?

Answer (score 3):

One simple way would be to do:

```
     Unprotect[Integer];
Integer /: 
  Format[r_Integer, FortranForm] := (SequenceForm[r // N, "_f"]);
Protect[Integer];
Unprotect[Rational];
Rational /: 
  Format[r_Rational, 
   FortranForm] := (SequenceForm[Numerator[r] // N, "_f", "/", 
    Denominator[r] // N, "_f"]);
Protect[Rational];
Protect[Integer];
tos = ToString[#, InputForm] &;
pow[a_Symbol, b_Integer] := tos[a] <> "^" <> tos[FortranForm[b]];
pow[a_Symbol, b_] := tos[a] <> "^(" <> tos[FortranForm[b]] <> ")";
pow[a_, b_] := "(" <> tos[a] <> ")^(" <> tos[FortranForm[b]] <> ")";
input = 22 + 
   4/5 x1 x1 x1 + (2 x2^4 + 343 Pi^4)/
    Sqrt[67 - x1 x1 x3 x3 + x2^(5/4)] + (4 x1 - x2)^(-3/2 q) + 
   Exp[-x1 x1 + 4 x2 x2 - 3 x1];
StringReplace[
 ToString[FortranForm[input /. Power -> pow], InputForm], {"\\" -> "",
   "\"" -> ""}]
```

which gives:

```
"22._f + (4 x1 - x2)^((-3._f*q)/2.) + E^(-x1^2._f + 4._f*x2^2._f - \
3._f*x1) + (4._f*x1^3._f)/5. + (67 + x2^(5._f/4._f) - x1^2._f \
x3^2._f)^(-1._f/2._f)*(343._f*Pi^4._f + 2._f*x2^4._f)"
```

Comment: @Mertig     Thanks! If input = 22 + (23/4 x1 - x2)^(3 dd/2), then some problem happens. Is it possible to find a more simple and safe method to deal with this problem?

Comment: @Orders Yes, that is possible. Try yourself: change ToString to ToString[ ..., InputForm] and then make it all into a nice function, say ToFortran. Use Module. Document everything you do and post it here (you can edit my post if you want).

Answer (score 1):

Simplifications/reordering that will separate the numbers from the `_f` pattern in a way that you seem to not want will take place on your given output expression if it is evaluated.

Therefore you will need some kind of hold function here.  I will use `HoldForm`.

```
input = 22 + 
   4/5 x1 x1 x1 + (2 x2^4 + 343 Pi^4)/
    Sqrt[67 - x1 x1 x3 x3 + x2^(5/4)] + (4 x1 - x2)^(-3/2 q) + 
   Exp[-x1 x1 + 4 x2 x2 - 3 x1];

input /. {
  Rational[n_, d_] :> Divide @@ HoldForm /@ {N@n f_, N@d f_},
  n_Integer :> HoldForm @@ {N[n] _f}
 }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: 5/4 should be 5._f/4._f

Comment: @Orders `5/4` is `Rational` not `Integer`.  Are you aware of the difference in the context of *Mathematica*?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to express this problem exactly. I mean , for the Rational 5/4, the integer 5 and 4 also should be changed.

Comment: @Orders Okay, I'll start on that.

Comment: @Orders Please take a look.  I do wonder what you're planning for this construct, and I hope it works.

Comment: @Wizard Thanks! I just want to change the anlytical expressions to fortranform, especially fortran95. However, FortranForm is really not good. Now I still face a big problem, e.g., how to change the input form to the output of fortranform?

Comment: @Orders have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19713/121)?

Comment: @Wizard Of course. But now I want to get a different form, like this post.